# HTTPS with github pages - www subdomain not found; others work

Tags: https, dns, github-pages

I have a github pages site whose DNS records I can't get to work correctly.

http://www.jeremydfoote.com, http://jeremydfoote.com, and https://jeremydfoote.com all resolve to https://jeremydfoote.com.

However, when HTTPS is combined with the www subdomain, the page isn't found (i.e., https://www.jeremydfoote.com/).

Right now, my DNS records only have A records pointing to the IP addresses found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#dns-configuration-errors)

Comment: How are you doing the redirection from `www` to the root (`@`)? Maybe try adding a CNAME to your DNS redirecting `www` to `@`

Comment: namecheap tells me that isn't allowed

Comment: Oh. I currently do this with CloudFlare. Have you considered switching?

Comment: I switched to CloudFlare and it worked. Thanks!